# AsyncPostBackTrigger can't find button inside a Grid EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Hello i added the following button inside of a grid:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="fancy-button" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Adauga un spatiu" />

    </EmptyDataTemplate>
```

The code behind for this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        adsDetails.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
    }
```

The button doesn't fire when i click on it and i tried to add :

```
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
```

I receive : "A control with ID 'Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'AddressGridViewUpdatePanel'. "

Any idea how i could fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncPostBackTrigger` needs the specified control in the same naming container (see remarks in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx)) as the parent UpdatePanel.

I suggest you to use [ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) to register your button as async trigger instead.

Comment: I had some problems to get this done but i made'it .I needed to set UpdateMode="Always" instead of conditional and used  Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "Button1";
            btn.Click += Button1_Click;
           ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn);